Pandas read_excel with nrows and skiprows and lazy-loading?
I am searching for ways to read an .xlsx file as chunks of dataframes, instead of loading the whole thing into memory. What exactly happens when I  pd.read_excel(nrows, skiprows, usecols) ? Is the whole file loaded into memory regardless?
If so, what other options do I have?I have looked into dask but little unsure if it works with excel files.

You could save your excel file as a csv file and use pd.read_csv with the chunksize parameter.

Excel file .xlsx are virtual file systems (zipped) and not designed to stream data from it. You can inspect it changing the extension. Basically a .xlsx is a zip file with a bunch of xml files inside and to open it you need to parse the entire spreadsheet XML file before being able to do anything with it. The best approach is to change the format of the data to csv or other faster formats.
